# Creating image histograms from all pictures in a folder

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram for each image in a folder, and save the plots of them into a CSV file. The user would enter the folder the images are saved, and then the files would get created and named accordingly

```
files = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] #loop to get all files from folder
for x in files:
    image = "x + 1"
    img2 = cv2.imread('similarImages/' + directory + '/' + image + '.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    histSim = cv2.calcHist([img2], [1], None, [256], [0, 256])  # create histo of each image
    np.savetxt('Test/similarImage' + x + '.csv', histSim, delimiter=',')  # save save plots to csv
```

From my previous knowledge of python, I've theory crafted the above code, but in classic fashion, it doesnt work (shocker)

Am I going along the right lines? If not could I get a nudge in the right direction, and if so, why doesnt it work?

It's been a while since I took on something like this, and such I am a little rusty, many thanks, Ben

Comment: Careful `image = "x + 1"` --> `image = x + "1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was the image variable was a string, and thus, when I was adding 1 to it, it was concatenating, and not adding the values, so using integers and then converting to a string when I needed it in the file path worked

```
image = 0
files = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # loop to get all files from folder
for x in files:

    image = x + 1
    image = str(image)
    img2 = cv2.imread('similarImages/' + directory + '/' + image + '.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    histSim = pd.DataFrame(cv2.calcHist([img2], [1], None, [256], [0, 256]))  # create histo of each image
    histSim.to_csv('Test/histogram' + image + '.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this task. If you want to store all the histograms in a single csv file you can use a list and append all the histogram values to it using this

```
df = []
df.append(cv2.calcHist(img, [1], None, [256], [0, 256])[:, 0]) # check if you want like this or transpose.
```

Then convert it to a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame` and store it as a csv file using `df.to_csv`

If you want to save each histogram to its independent csv file then you can:

```
histSim = pd.DataFrame(cv2.calcHist(img, [1], None, [256], [0, 256]))
histSim.to_csv('histogram.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: To save each histogram individually, would I have to put that code into a for loop, also, would I still use the image variable to create sequential filenames?

Comment: doing that gives me this error: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:160: error: (-215:Assertion failed) j < nimages in function 'cv::histPrepareImages'`

Comment: could you make sure that the value of image is not none. You would use img2 and not img in `cv2.calcHist` liked you had written in the question.